# Change colors on grand college WordPress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the colors on grand college WordPress theme.
First I tried to do it using back end and it wasn't not working.

So I tried to change those from the CSS file, in that theme the CSS file is inside a PHP file.

However I found the line and changed the color and uploaded it to the server, but still the colors have not changed.

I cleaned the cache and checked but it isn't working.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: Can you share the url ?

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: http://incatechlk.ipage.com/websites/2015/mercury/

Comment: I want to change the color of header and footer

Answer (score 1):

Use developer tools to find out which css file and line controls appearance of element you want to change (imho Google Chrome has a good one). If still no changes are visible, try `!important`. For example: `h1 {color: blue!important;}`

Comment: yes I tried those I am using firebug and I found the correct css ine but the problem is when I changed and upload the css file the changes won't appear

Answer (score 0):

Use !important in your style.css

```
div.footer-wrapper {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your footer is using a background image, so if you like to change its background color, you first need to remove the background image, you can do it in many ways.
for example you can add following code to your style.css file

```
div.footer-wrapper {
background-image: none !important;
background-color: #abcdea !important;
}
```

for your header background color add following code to your style.css file:

```
div.inner-header-wrapper {
background-color: #abcdea !important; 
}
```